# Get method not working in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi I am developing one application in web api2 and angularjs. I have some routing problems in accessing urls from angularjs.

I am trying to access below url.

```
var url = '/api/projects/4/processes';
```

My controller code looks like below.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/processes")]
public class processesController : ApiController
{      
    [ActionName("projects/{projectsId}/processes")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
    }
}
```

I am getting 404 error. I am not able to hit the url.

This is my webapi.config file.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    //routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First ensure that attribute routing is enabled before convention-based routes.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",            
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

if the intended url is `/api/projects/4/processes` Then the given action needs to update its route template to match. The controller already has a route prefix but that can be overridden by prefixing the route template with the tilde `~`

Use a tilde (~) on the method attribute to override the route prefix:

```
//GET /api/projects/4/processes
[HttpGet]    
[Route("~/api/projects/{projectsId:int}/processes")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int projectsId) { ... }
```

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

Comment: shouldn't the route argument name match? `Get(int projectsId)`

Comment: my url is   var url = '/api/projects/4/processes'; and controller looks like   [HttpGet]
        [Route("~/api/projects/{projectsId:int}/processes")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int projectsId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
        }

Comment: sorry i changed to projectsId and it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can i implement same url structure to post method? Thank you

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole yes you can. just make sure to tag the action with `[HttpPost]`  attribute.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole I would also advise you read up on the documentation linked to in the answer. It will give you a better understanding on this topic.

Comment: yes thank you. I am not good in playing around urls. Now post working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

In your case, the URL should be,

`http://yourUrl/api/processes?projectsId=yourValue`

Also, change your ActionName to Route attribute,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/processes")]
public class ProcessesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("projects/{projectsId}/processes"),HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int projectsId)
    {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
    }
}
```

New URL - http://yourUrl/api/processes/projects/2/processes

[More info on Attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that attribute routing should be enabled before convention-based routes.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

then you can make routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",            
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Define Methods like :

```
//GET /api/projects/4/processes ([ActionName("projects/{projectsId}/processes")])
[RoutePrefix("api/processes")]
public class processesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]    
    [Route("~/api/projects/{projectId:int}/processes")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int projectId) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a route prefix, which means the url of action would be RoutePrefix + ActionRoute

i.e. HTTP GET api/processes/projects/{projectsId}/processes

Ref [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the "[Authorize]" attribute on the ValuesController class was all I needed...
All credit to [DotNetTutorials](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/creating-web-api-application/)

From the article:
“api/{controller}/{id}”

At this point, if you use the following URI in the browser, you will get an error stating – Authorization has been denied for this request.

http://localhost:xxxxx/api/values

To get rid of this error, comment ***Authorize*** attribute on the ValuesController class. This is related to security which we will discuss in a later article.